# get_post_meta in one post only

Tags: post-meta

I have a rough demo here to try and illustrate my problem.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk

I have six pages with titles -  Page One, Two etc.

On a index/home page I'm creating a btn/div to link to each page.

On one of the btn's I want to put an extra label/mark.

On the page connected to that btn I have created a custom field with the name of label.

In the loop I am checking for this custom field with get_post_meta. If it's there I'm adding a  to the div.

My problem is the  is added to the other div's after the after the div/page that has the 'label' custom field.

In the example page http://www.ttmt.org.uk

I want the added label on Page Three but it also appearing on the after that.

```
    <?php

        $frontAgrs = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'tag' => 'group',
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC'
        );

        $frontLoop = new WP_Query($frontAgrs);

        if($frontLoop->have_posts()):
            while($frontLoop->have_posts()):
                $frontLoop->the_post();

        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'label', true) != ''){
            $label = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'label', true);
            $label = '<em>'.$label.'</em>';
        }   

        $btnName = get_the_title();

    ?>

    <?php echo '<div class="theDiv" ><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'"><span>'.$btnName.'</span>'.$label.'</a></div>' ?>


    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put an exception into your conditional:

```
if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'label', true) != ''){
   $label = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'label', true);
   $label = '<em>'.$label.'</em>';
} else {
   $label = '':
}
```